# Why does this happen with Python's list.sort?

Tags: python

Given the code:

```
a=['a','b','c','d']
b=a[::-1]
print b
c=zip(a,b)
print c
c.sort(key=lambda x:x[1])#
print c
```

It prints:

```
['d', 'c', 'b', 'a']
[('a', 'd'), ('b', 'c'), ('c', 'b'), ('d', 'a')]
[('d', 'a'), ('c', 'b'), ('b', 'c'), ('a', 'd')]
```

Why does [('a', 'd'), ('b', 'c'), ('c', 'b'), ('d', 'a')]  change to [('d', 'a'), ('c', 'b'), ('b', 'c'), ('a', 'd')]?

---

Similarly, given:

```
c.sort(key=lambda x:3)#
print c
```

It prints:

```
[('a', 'd'), ('b', 'c'), ('c', 'b'), ('d', 'a')]
```

Nothing changes - why?

Comment: It's a little hard to tell what aspects of the Python you've used you're having trouble with. Lists? Lambdas? Do you understand what "lambda x:3" means, for instance? Or x[1]?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

because x[1] means *second*

use

```
c.sort(key=lambda x:x[0])
```

Answer (score 3):

You've sorted `c` using the second item as the key, and the second item does indeed go up, just as you asked for it to go up.  What's so surprising?!

Answer (score 1):

```
from operator import itemgetter    
c.sort(key=itemgetter(0))
```

Answer (score 1):

As the others have said, `[1]` refers to the second element, so the elements in the first part are sorted that way.

As for the second part, `list.sort()` is [stable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability), so elements that evaluate to the same key will maintain their relative position in the sequence. This is why using `.sort(reverse=True)` can give different results from `.sort()` followed by `.reverse()`.

Answer (score 0):

You've sorted the list using the second element of each tuple as a key so you get the tuples ordered by their second element (Notice the 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' in increasing order). What's the problem?